# Why is `ref mut` on a for loop binding not the same as `&mut` on the variable being looped over?

Tags: rust

In [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/borrow/ref.html), it says:

> A `ref` borrow on the left side of an assignment is equivalent to an `&` borrow on the right side.

I thought these two `for` loops would be equivalent:

Compiles successfully:

```
let mut v2 = vec![1, 2, 3];
for i in &mut v2 {
    *i = *i + 1;
}
println!("{:?}", v2);
```

Does not compile:

```
let mut v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
for ref mut i in v1 {
    *i = *i + 1;
}
println!("{:?}", v1);
```

It seems `v` is moved:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `v1`
 --> src/main.rs:6:22
  |
3 |     for ref mut i in v1 {
  |                      -- value moved here
...
6 |     println!("{:?}", v1);
  |                      ^^ value used here after move
  |
  = note: move occurs because `v1` has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you quote from the book is a rule for normal assignments such as those by `let`. For example:

```
let x = &42;
let ref x = 42;
```

But the name binding in a `for` loop is a bit different:

- The value to be looped around is converted into an iterator (`<v1 as IntoIterator>::into_iter()`) Lets call the result of that `it`.
- Then the `it.next()` is called repeatedly:

  - If it returns `Some(_)` then the value of that is bound to your variable. Just as if you wrote `let Some(ref mut i) = it.next()` or `let Some(mut i) = it.next()`. Here is where the `ref` matters.
  - If it returns `None` the loop ends.

So in the `for` loop case, the `ref` and the `&` are not equivalent.

When you use the `&` at the right side of a loop, it does not change the binding of the variable directly; you just change the type of the object iterated. Then, all comes down to the implementation of `IntoIterator` for `Vec<_>` vs that for `&Vec<_>`.

- If you iterate `Vec<T>`, it takes ownership of the vector and the iteration returns the values themselves. So `for i in v1` consumes the vector and the `i` has the type of the contained values `T`.
- If you iterate `&Vec<T>`, it borrows the vector and the iteration return pointers to the contained values `&T`, so in `for i in &v1` the type of `i` is actually a pointer to the values. The same effect can be got with `for i in v1.iter()`.
- If you iterate `&mut Vec<T>`, is just like the previous one but mutable, so the iteration returns values of type `&mut T`.

The conclusion is that using `ref` in a `for` loop is not probably so useful.